# Error while implenting the Faster R-CNN Object detection algorithm

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, torchvision, faster-rcnn

I am trying to implement the Faster R-CNN object detection algorithm and I have an unusual error.
While trying to call the `train_one_epoch` function in this [colab tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/vision/blob/temp-tutorial/tutorials/torchvision_finetuning_instance_segmentation.ipynb#scrollTo=at-h4OWK0aoc&line=6&uniqifier=1) I had an error in the `loss_dict = model(images, targets)`which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/detection/engine.py) .
The exact error that i had is :

```
    101         cell_anchors = self.cell_anchors
    102         assert cell_anchors is not None
--> 103         assert len(grid_sizes) == len(strides) == len(cell_anchors)
    104 
    105         for size, stride, base_anchors in zip(

AssertionError:
```

Anyone have an idea ? And thanks in advance !

Comment: I know what it means, but I'm not familiar with the faster rcnn tutorial. You have to find the places where grid_sizes, strides and cell_anchors are initialized. The error means that the lengths of these lists are not equal and throws an error because they should be for the code to work. I can't really help you more than that

Comment: @cbolwerk yes thank you, you're right I was able to fix this problem by adjusting the parameters and the input of my Faster R-CNN function. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve this problem and it's just by adding adjusting the size of the AnchorGenerator and their corresponding aspect ratios in the Faster R-CNN function

```
ft_anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(
    sizes=((32, 64, 128),), aspect_ratios=((0.5, 1.0, 2.0),)
)
ft_model = FasterRCNN(
    backbone=ft_backbone,
    num_classes=num_classes,
    rpn_anchor_generator=ft_anchor_generator)
```